# SQL Server Conversion Exception: Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project where the goal is to convert an existing application to SQL Server. However, I am running into issues with ID generation - specifically, the conversion of data types.

The hibernate annotations for my ID column are as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="ID_GEN", strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@TableGenerator(name="ID_GEN", table="[$SSMA_seq_SEQ_EXAMPLE_ID]")
@Column(name="ID", unique="true", nullable="false")
public String getId() {
    return this.id;
}
```

This ID column of this table maps to a `varchar(50)`, while the `$SSMA_seq_SEQ_EXAMPLE_ID` maps to a table with a single `id` column with a data type of `numeric(38,0)`.

When I attempt an insert (by creating a Java object and persisting it), I get the following exception: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error converting data type varchar to numeric`.

Conceptually, it makes sense that a `numeric(38,0)` would fit into a `varchar(50)`, but it seems that the SQL Server [implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) does not work in this case. Unfortunately, changing the database definition is not an option at this point in time.

Are there any global settings that will force this conversion in either hibernate or SQL Server? Because I am using hibernate to generate the IDs, I do not have much control over the SQL that is generated to grab an ID before committing this object to the database.

Comment: From the error message it doesn't look like the problem is fitting a NUMERIC(38, 0) into VARCHAR(50). It looks like it's the other way around - trying to convert a VARCHAR(50) into a NUMERIC(38, 0).

Comment: Also note that if you have IDENTITY column in your SQL Server, it is basically not supposed to be inserted with explicit values in most cases. (and SSMA has some logic to convert Oracle sequences usage to SQL Server IDENTITY, but you would have to configure it in SSMA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom Generator that assumed the known data types and did the conversions. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229833/override-hibernate-annotations) for full details.